# How do I use GridBagConstraints setRows and setColumns?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

How do I use `setRows` and setColumns to change the amount of rows and columns in my window?

Here's a copy of my code and where I tried to implement the set rows and columns:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.*;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public class GUI
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GUI();
    }


    public GUI()
    {

        JFrame AG = new JFrame("Adventure Game");
        AG.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        AG.setResizable(true);
        AG.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p=new JPanel();

        p.setLayout (new GridBagLayout());

        AG.add(p);
        GridBagConstraints GBC = new GridBagConstraints();
        GridLayout.setRows(100);//heres the set rows<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        GridLayout.setColumns(100);//heres the set columns<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        AG.getContentPane().add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JButton saveButton =new JButton("Save");
        JButton loadButton =new JButton("Load");
        JButton optionsButton = new JButton("Options");

        JLabel textBox= new JLabel("Story line will go here.");

        JLabel label11 = new JLabel("Test 1");
        GBC.gridx = 0;
        GBC.gridy = 1;

        p.add(label11,GBC);
        JLabel label12 = new JLabel("Test 2");
        GBC.gridx = 0;
        GBC.gridy = 2;
        p.add(label12,GBC);
        JLabel label13 = new JLabel("Test 3");
        GBC.gridx = 0;
        GBC.gridy = 3;
        p.add(label13,GBC);
        JLabel label14 = new JLabel("Test 4");
        GBC.gridx = 0;
        GBC.gridy = 5;
        p.add(label14,GBC);

        AG.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you try to achive? You need to manipulate rows/columns with help of `GridBagConstraints`: `gridx`,`gridy`,`gridwidth`,`gridheight`

Comment: yeah I'm trying to work out how to lay out my buttons because i want for example to be able to have blank cells so i could have a button at 0,1 0,2 0,3 then miss one and 0,5

Comment: In that case I recommend you to add dummy label(`new JLabel(" ");`) to  0.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridBagConstraints` work with the `GridBagLayout`, not the `GridLayout`. Your call to GridLayout doesn't do anything.

To set the rows and columns with GridBagConstraints, you need to use `GBC.gridx = ...;` and `GBC.gridy = ...;`

Comment: thats what i have used but the amount of columns and rows is relative to the amount of objects so i want to predefine how many cells in the x and y axis

Comment: you cannot predefine row / column count in GridBagLayout... It makes no sense! Either you've got a component in the row/column or you don't, and if you don't GridBagLayout won't lay it out (ie 0 height & width)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to place gaps between your buttons, empty GridBag cells are not the way to do it;  use the `insets` of your GridBagConstraints for that.

To make a component in a GridBagLayout disappear without the other components shifting around, place the button in a JPanel with a CardLayout, and make sure you add that JPanel to your GridBagLayout instead of the button:

```
private JButton optionalButton;

private void buildWindow() {
    // ...

    optionalButton = new JButton("Optional Action");

    JPanel optionalButtonPanel = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    optionalButtonPanel.add(optionalButton, "BUTTON");
    optionalButtonPanel.add(new JLabel(), "BLANK");

    // ...
}

private void setOptionalButtonVisible(boolean visible) {
    Container optionalButtonPanel = optionalButton.getParent();
    CardLayout layout = (CardLayout) optionalButtonPanel.getLayout();
    layout.show(optionalButtonPanel, visible ? "BUTTON" : "BLANK");
}
```

CardLayout always displays one and only one of its components, but it sizes its associated container to fit all the components, including the invisible ones.